# There are at least 3 english translations of Sha'ar HaGilgulim with the same cover, but different page lengths and publishers. What's the difference?

Tags: history, mysticism-kabbalah, judaism

*Edit added at bottom of page.*

I have the one from Eichlers with 918 pages, but I noticed these others, and I am wondering if the one I own is missing chapters or pages of the translation that another english version is not? I don't want to pay twice since they are fairly expensive books, but if there is something missing in the 918 page version that is in the 914 or 946 page version, then it is worth it to me.

946 page version, publisher "thirty six", ISBN: B071YZYJPH. https://www.amazingjewishbooks.com/p-1162/B071YZYJPH/shaar_hagilgulim_gate_of_reincarnation.html

C.I.S. publishing, 918 pages,
SKU CISSHAR. https://www.eichlers.com/gate-of-reincarnations-shaar-hagilgulim-cisshar.html

914 pages, SKU35433. Doesn't say publisher. https://mekorjudaica.com/sha-ar-hagilgulim-gate-of-reincarnations.html?gclid=EAIaIQobChMI8MC-kOii9gIVYw6tBh0AlgUpEAQYAyABEgIaVPD_BwE

So ummm, anyone want to help me learn Hebrew? *Joking face emoji*. But seriously, it can be a bit tricky to even locate the good english translations from the less good ones.

*Edit: I've been told there is both a longer manuscript Hebrew version, 72 chapters I believe, and a shorter manuscript Hebrew version. Are the english versions translations of the longer version, or the shorter version? If it's the shorter one, is the long manuscript version available in english? Are these censored at all?*

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/134643/discussion-on-question-by-shipbuilding-there-are-at-least-3-english-translations).